# wordpress insecure URL fix issue

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I am a beginner in PHP & i am in process of converting all my http links to https.

Following is my code footer.php

```
function css_generator() {
    /* @footer_background_image */
    .td-footer-wrapper::before {
        background-image: url('@footer_background_image');
    }

$td_css_compiler->load_setting('footer_background_image');
```

Where can i apply preg_replace function to replace http link with https?. The value of footer_background_image is always getting generated as http

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at this from the wrong way. Wordpress has built-in support for HTTPS for the backend, wich can be enabled in wp-config.php, and for the front-end, wich can be used by changing the URL in your admin->reading page.

If you have a bunch of hardcoded links rather than soft, Wordpress generated links, you can choose to use .htaccess to force the user to change to HTTPS.

Do note that HTTPS data can not be cached and this will may make your site slower for visitors. Depending on the type of site this can be a big deal.

Comment: Hi, I have tried changing the Base URL from settings page to https, but still the link to only above item are in http. I am using Newspaper theme

Comment: If you really want to use preg_replace, you can use it in the index.php file on all of the content (even get_header() and get_footer()).